# problems recursivley building a UL/LI in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a tree of LI/UL elements from an interal object I have in javascript. Making the top level elements works fine, but then recursivley building the child elements seems to be causing me problems.

in the code below `#DynaTree` is the  `UL` element that is the root of my tree.  `tv` is my object that represents the tree - I've actually stubbed out the child creation code to something more simple just to get it working. You can also see the commented out line where I tried a different approach. In either case, I get no error, but I never see the child elements appended to the first level of objects.

```
     for(i = 0; i < tv.getSize();i++){
        var t = tv.getTaskAt(i);
         var newul = $("<ul>" + t.TaskName +  "(" + t.GUID + ")</ul>");
         makeChildren(newul);
         $("#DynaTree").append(newul);
     }

     function makeChildren(el){
         var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
         console.log("Making Children Elements " + randomnumber);
         for(var i = 0; i < randomnumber;i++){
             var newElement = $("<ul>New Element</ul");
                             /************************
                              Neither one of these methods works!
                             ***********************/
             //$("#DynaTree", el).append(newElement);
             el.append(newElement);
         }

    }
```

`

Feels like I'm missing something obvious. Any help much appreciated.

-ace

Comment: The `ul` isn't closed in makeChildren, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I now feel very sily. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Andrew is right, you are missing the closing bracket in your `</ul>` tag creating the child.  That is causing it to create a `<ul>` node with no content. On a side note the code you posted has no [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) in it. Recursion involves a function that calls itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the closing `>` at the end of creating the new element, should read...

```
`var newElement = $("<ul>New Element</ul>");`
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andrew pointing out that the UL link wasn't closed off

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it right, you are trying to create these ul/li at runtime. You can use the jquery template plugin for the same. More info at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/